# Html.EditorFor method for interface attributes

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, interface, metadata, html-helper, mvc-editor-templates

I'm a beginner ASP.NET MVC 3 web-developer and have this problem:

There are several view models, that have similar logic and I've come to idea to have one common EditorTemplate for them to be rendered by `Html.EditorFor`.

The template is named "`ExistOrCreateNewInput.cshtml`" and is strongly-typed with `IExistOrCreateNewInput` interface class:

```
public interface IExistOrCreateNewInput
{
  int? existEntId { get; set; }
  IUnapprovedNewEntityCreateInput createInput { get; set; }
}
```

Template's content is something like:

```
@model IExistOrCreateNewInput

<h2>Add or choose</h2>
@* here put some common js code *@
Html.EditorFor(o => o.existEntId)
Html.EditorFor(o => o.createInput)
```

Suppose I have some sort of models that implement this interface, for example:

```
public class FirstModelInput : IExistOrCreateNewInput
{
  [Display(Name="First")]
  [UIHint("Lookup")]
  public int? existEntId {get; set;}

  [UIHint("PaperCreateInput")]
  public PaperCreateInput paperCreateInput {get; set;}

  public IUnapprovedNewEntityCreateInput createInput
  {
      get
      {
          return paperCreateInput;
      }
      set { }
  }
}

public class SecondModelInput : IExistOrCreateNewInput
{
  [Display(Name="Second")]
  [UIHint("Lookup")]
  public int? existEntId {get; set;}

  [UIHint("ThesisCreateInput")]
  public ThesisCreateInput thesisCreateInput {get; set;}

  public IUnapprovedNewEntityCreateInput createInput
  {
      get
      {
          return thesisCreateInput;
      }
      set { }
  }
}
public class ThirdModelInput : IExistOrCreateNewInput
{
  ...
}
```

Where `PaperCreateInput` and `ThesisCreateInput` classes implement `IUnapprovedNewEntityCreateInput` interface.
So, I want my view model

```
public class SomeGlobalViewModel
{
  [Required]
  string name {get; set;}
  [UIHint("ExistOrCreateNewInput")]
  FirstModelInput firstModel {get; set;}
}
```

to render correctly the attribute "firstModel" with `Html.EditorFor(o => o.firstModel)` method.
Now I know that EditorFor method is dealing with Metadata, so probably my question should be like "*how can I pass metadata of attributes to base interface attributes*". Correct me, if I'm wrong.
Anyway, I need those helper methods

```
Html.EditorFor(o => o.existEntId)
Html.EditorFor(o => o.createInput)
```

in my editor template (strongly-typed with interface) to render my Models' attributes as I declared them in implementing classes:

```
[UIHint("Lookup")]
public int? existEntId {get; set;}  
[UIHint("PaperCreateInput")]
public PaperCreateInput createInput {get; set;}
```

Thanks in advance.
Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: I wonder how does your code compile in the first place because the `FirstModelInput`, `SecondModelInput`, ... classes **do not** implement the `IExistOrCreateNewInput` interface. In this interface the `createInput` property is of type `IUnapprovedNewEntityCreateInput`, not `PaperCreateInput` or `ThesisCreateInput`.

Comment: Sorry, missed that part in my examples. Check out fixed classes above. Thanks.

Comment: Your Views need to be strongly typed based on concrete implementations, interfaces do not work.

Comment: Any insights on how can I implement that "one editorTemplate" idea? Cause that "here put some common js code" section has a lot of code that I don't want to copy-paste in all my views. And basically, all those FirstModelInput, SecondModelInput have same logic in them, just need to render them in the same way.

Comment: You can use "@model dynamic" in the editor template (*.cshtml), and replace @Html.EditorFor({lambda exp}) for @Html.Editor("FirstModelInput"), since expression tree cannot contain dynamic operation.

Comment: Thanks, wnascimento. Any other ideas? I can't believe no one ever encountered this kind of problem before.